# WCF / WFS - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, wcf, mapserver

Nowadays i'm working with Mapcript / Mapserver. I would like to know how to used WFS (Web Feature Service) with ASP.NET.

I think i need to use WCF, right? Is there any tutorial or framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best framework to handle geographic infomation in ASP.NET is no doubt GDAL: http://www.gdal.org/ I havn't used their WFS-driver that was released this year but It would be the first thing that I tried.